# C++ Code Style - Best place to create objects

Tags: c++, performance, coding-style, readability

My friend and I were discussing the other day which style of code is better.

Case A:

```
int function()
{
    largeobject a;
    //do some stuff without a
    //do some stuff with a
}
```

Case B:

```
int function()
{
    //do some stuff without a
    largeobject a;
    //do some stuff with a
}
```

So which code is better in term of speed and readability.

Comment: Side note, they are both function declarations: a function called `a` that takes no arguments and returns a `largeobject`.

Comment: Regarding function declaration you should check out the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2)

Comment: Make it readable first. The compiler will certainly find the most optimal machine code in either case.

Comment: In terms of readability, it might be an indication that you want two functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should declare variables/instances of object as locally as possible. So, in this case, B would be the best option.

Consider that if you declare it at the top of your function body other people reading your code might wonder where you actually use the object. Therefore, by having the declaration close to where you actually use it will makes it easier to read.

There should not be any huge performance difference between case A and B.

There are some special cases such as allocating big chunks of memory or a thread pool for example. In these cases, since it might be time and ressources consumming you might need to find a better place to allocate them.

If you new to programming, you might want to consider reading Scott Meyers book, [Effective C++](http://www.amazon.ca/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1341587097&sr=8-1). Item 26 talks about it : Postpone variable definitions as long as possible.

Comment: agree, but objects with a full method/function scope should go straight to the beginning of the function/method

Comment: @BigMike Of course since it'll be used during the whole method/function

Answer (score 2):

You should use case B. There is not need to create an object before you need it.

Also, your compiler will not interpret `largeobject a();` as the creation of an object with the default constructor, but as a **function declaration**. This is called "most vexing parse".

Answer (score 0):

Case B is best. This situation explained in S.Mcconnell book - Complete Code. And you wrong with:

> So which code is better in term of speed and readability.

Case B is better by other reasons.

Comment: I'm curious. Would you care to give a hint on what reasons that are?